# how to differentiate two very long strings in c++?

Tags: string, algorithm, memory-management, string-matching, information-theory

I would like to solve 
[Levenshtein_distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) this problem where length of string is too huge .

**Edit2 :**
As [Bobah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267482/bobah) said that title is miss leading , so i had updated the title of questoin .
Initial `title was` how to declare 100000x100000 2-d integer in c++ ? 
`Content was` 
There is any way to declare int x[100000][100000] in c++.
When i declare it globally then compiler produces  `error: size of array ‘x’ is too large` .
One method could be using `map< pair< int , int > , int > mymap` .

 But allocating and deallocating takes more time .
 There is any other way like uisng `vector<int> myvec` ;

Comment: Do you have 40 GB memory on your machine? Because that's how much the array would take.

Comment: Do you know that your array will take 40 or 80 GB? Do you have that much RAM?

Comment: Why do you need such large array ?

Comment: @P0W I need this to solve a Dynamic programming Question .

Comment: @interjay No i don't have that much RAM .

Comment: *I need this to solve a Dynamic programming Question* When I read *dynamic programming* I think *efficiency*. This is not that.

Comment: @user3919801 Well in that case you probably need to re-analyze your problem, and figure out better algorithm

Comment: @ta.speot.is check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance question for string of length 100000 .

Comment: And now I see this is heading toward a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/232397)

Comment: @user3919801 If you think about it for a second, you don't really need a whole array, since most elements in most iterations will be the same. Bascially you will need 2 * 100000 element `string`s and a `vector` that can contain a maximum of 100000 transformations from string `a` to string `b`.

Comment: @user3919801 The wikipedia article you linked contains an algorithm that only requires two matrix rows.

Comment: @interjay i tried for first approach .

Comment: This has nothing to do with RAM. On modern architectures, maximum size of an object is determined by the size of *virtual address space* not by the "amount of RAM" on the machine, as some comments incorrectly suggest.

Comment: Use the iterative version of the algorithm with matrix rows.

Comment: @AndreyT: And? While it´s certainly true, the lack of RAM will cause problems anyway. Swapfiles etc. are usually limited too, and if nothing else, it will be slow.

Comment: @AndreyT: Do you REALLY believe that saying something is "virtual" is enough to let it exist even if no physical resource is there to sustain it? Hardware sellers loves you!

Comment: rename it to "how to diff two *very* long strings in c++", it will be a hit

Comment: @bobah You can edit content of question .

Comment: @deviantfan: Whether it will be slow or not will depend on how *local* is the program's access to that large array. If the program constantly rescans the whole array, then it will indeed be slow. But if the program performs intensive processing in a localized region of the array, before moving to another localized region, there will be nothing slow about it. The concept is known as *working set*. And the matter of "slow" or "fast" depends only on whether the working set fits into RAM. The total size of the array is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Emilio Garavaglia: Your comment makes no sense. Any modern 64-bit system will easily let you allocate 40GB array and will sustain it, even if the amount of RAM in that system is minimal. There's nothing tricky about it. I suspect you have no idea about how virtual memory works, if you believe that "sustaining" 40GB array somehow requires 40GB of RAM.

Comment: The art of efficient modern programming is in large degree about knowing how to design and organize your algorithm to efficiently process 400GB of data through a much smaller RAM window.

Comment: @AndyT: Your suspects are wrong. I know what virtual memory is since 1981. I know how it works and I know WHY IT CANNOT WORK EFFICIENTLY in executing algorithms LIKE THEONE INDICATED BY THE OP. The system LET you do it, but if you try your system will doom you out for hours until the algorithm complete. 64+GB must in any casee xist somewhere, and the time to move it up and down gets multiplied by the number of time you do it. If the bandwidth is low and the algorithm is O^2 be prepared to 64G transferred for 1bilion times from disk to memory and back.

Comment: @AndyT: It's not a case that Levenshtein_distance is not normally implemented that way, but by means of its differential, with an integration on output.

Answer (score 3):

For memory blocks that large, the best approach is dynamic allocation using the operating system's facilities for adding virtual memory to the process.

However, look how large a block you are trying to allocate:

```
 40 000 000 000 bytes
```

I take my previous advice back. For a block that large, the best approach is to analyze the problem and figure out a way to use less memory.

Comment: 1TB RAM is already a reality in server world, but agree, the diff does not need to load everything to the RAM unless it needs to be deterministic to the last point.

Answer (score 2):

Filling the edit distance matrix can be done each row at a time. Remembering the previous row is enough to compute the current row. This observation reduces space usage from quadratic to linear. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very interesting, but the title is misleading.

This is what you need in terms of data model (x - first string, y - second string, * - distance matrix).

```
      y <-- first string (scrolls from top down)

      y
  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  <- second string (scrolls from left to right)
      y *  *  *

      y *  *  *

      y *  *  * <-- distance matrix (a donut) scrolls together with strings
                    and grows/shrinks when needed, as explained below
      y
```

Have two relatively long (but still << N) character buffers and relatively small ( << buffers size) rectangular (start from square) distance matrix.

Make the matrix a [donut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) - bi-dimentional ring buffer (can use the one from boost, or just std::deque).

When string fragments currently covered by the matrix are 100% match shift both buffers by one, rotate the donut around both axes, recalculating one new row/column in the distance matrix.

When match is <100% and is less than configured threshold then grow the size of the both dimensions of the donut without dropping any rows/columns and do it until either match gets above the threshold or you reach the maximum donut size. When match ratio hits the threshold from the below you need to scroll donut discarding head of x and y buffers and at the same time aligning them (only X needs moving by 1 when the distance matrix tells that X[i] does not exist in Y, but X[i+1,i+m] matches Y[j, j+m-1]).

As a result you will have a simple yet very efficient heuristic diff engine with deterministic limited memory footprint and all memory can be pre-allocated at startup so no dynamic allocation will slow it down at runtime.

[Apache v2 license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html), in case you decide to go for it.

Comment: What will be the time complexity if this algorithm ?

Comment: `k * O(N)`, `k` defined by configuration parameters, mainly the largest possible size of the "donut" (the larger the slower)